# div equivalent to mod

Tags: math-operators

What's the easiest way to define a `\bdiv` equivalent to `\bmod`, i.e., a binary operator for integer division?

I tried `\meaning\bmod`, but got very primitive TeX commands, so I'm sure there's a higher-level way to define it that would give me the Roman font and binary operation spacing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can find the definition of `\bmod` in `latex.ltx` or [`source2e`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf).
The example below just replaces `mod` with `div`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\bdiv}{%
  \nonscript\mskip-\medmuskip\mkern5mu%
  \mathbin{\operator@font div}\penalty900\mkern5mu%
  \nonscript\mskip-\medmuskip
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[ a\bmod b \]
\[ a\bdiv b \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thank you. Now I just have to find where Ubuntu put those two files on my system. :-)

Comment: @TOB Just run `texdoc source2e` or `kpsewhich latex.ltx`.